# Sonata Classification Bundle route problem

Tags: sonata

After I installed classification bundle my application broke with this exception:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template `None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route 'admin_app_sonataclassificationcategory_create' not found`

Somebody faced it?